# Errors to pip install chatterbot and spacy

Tags: python, pip

I'am installing Chatterbot and when i you get the Spacy package, but gives a giant error and closes the pip, I only have python 3.8 64bits installed on my computer

I used the pip install, pip -U and the method to download the wheel and install by it, also gives several errors

```
pip install git+git://github.com/gunthercox/ChatterBot.git@master
Collecting git+git://github.com/gunthercox/ChatterBot.git@master
  Cloning git://github.com/gunthercox/ChatterBot.git (to revision master) to c:\users\dougl\appdata\local\temp\pip-req-build-iklnu38l
  Running command git clone -q git://github.com/gunthercox/ChatterBot.git 'C:\Users\dougl\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-req-build-iklnu38l'
Collecting mathparse<0.2,>=0.1
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/c3/e5/4910fb85950cb960fcf3f5aabe1c8e55f5c9201788a1c1302b570a7e1f84/mathparse-0.1.2-py3-none-any.whl
Collecting nltk<4.0,>=3.2
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/f6/1d/d925cfb4f324ede997f6d47bea4d9babba51b49e87a767c170b77005889d/nltk-3.4.5.zip
Collecting pint>=0.8.1
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/15/9d/bf177ebbc57d25e9e296addc14a1303d1e34d7964af5df428a8332349c42/Pint-0.9-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting python-dateutil<2.8,>=2.7
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/74/68/d87d9b36af36f44254a8d512cbfc48369103a3b9e474be9bdfe536abfc45/python_dateutil-2.7.5-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting pyyaml<5.2,>=5.1
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/e3/e8/b3212641ee2718d556df0f23f78de8303f068fe29cdaa7a91018849582fe/PyYAML-5.1.2.tar.gz
Collecting spacy<2.2,>=2.1
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/58/f2/5a23bb7251988da474eec844b692760cb0a317912291afc77b516f399cff/spacy-2.1.8.tar.gz
  Installing build dependencies ... error
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: 'c:\program files\python38\python.exe' 'c:\program files\python38\lib\site-packages\pip' install --ignore-installed --no-user --prefix 'C:\Users\dougl\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-1d3wxwlm\overlay' --no-warn-script-location --no-binary :none: --only-binary :none: -i https://pypi.org/simple -- setuptools 'wheel>0.32.0,<0.33.0' Cython 'cymem>=2.0.2,<2.1.0' 'preshed>=2.0.1,<2.1.0' 'murmurhash>=0.28.0,<1.1.0' 'thinc>=7.0.8,<7.1.0'
       cwd: None
  Complete output (68 lines):
  Collecting setuptools
    Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/6a/9a/50fadfd53ec909e4399b67c74cc7f4e883488035cfcdb90b685758fa8b34/setuptools-41.4.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
  Collecting wheel<0.33.0,>0.32.0
    Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/ff/47/1dfa4795e24fd6f93d5d58602dd716c3f101cfd5a77cd9acbe519b44a0a9/wheel-0.32.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl
  Collecting Cython
    Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/a5/1f/c7c5450c60a90ce058b47ecf60bb5be2bfe46f952ed1d3b95d1d677588be/Cython-0.29.13.tar.gz
  Collecting cymem<2.1.0,>=2.0.2
    Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/8b/dc/0976e04cc46f86e0dd3ee3797ec68057eaafebf31daca9a076dc138b9920/cymem-2.0.2.tar.gz
  Collecting preshed<2.1.0,>=2.0.1
    Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/0b/14/c9aa735cb9c131545fc9e23031baccb87041ac9215b3d75f99e3cf18f6a3/preshed-2.0.1.tar.gz
  Collecting murmurhash<1.1.0,>=0.28.0
    Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/22/e9/411be1845f1ac07ae3bc40a4b19ba401819baed4fa63b4f5ef28b2300eb4/murmurhash-1.0.2.tar.gz
  Collecting thinc<7.1.0,>=7.0.8
    Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/92/39/ea2a3d5b87fd52fc865fd1ceb7b91dca1f85e227d53e7a086d260f6bcb93/thinc-7.0.8.tar.gz
  Collecting blis<0.3.0,>=0.2.1
    Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/59/9e/84a83616cbe5daa94909da38b780e93bf566dc2113c3dc35d7b4cad52f63/blis-0.2.4.tar.gz
  Collecting wasabi<1.1.0,>=0.0.9
    Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/f4/c1/d76ccdd12c716be79162d934fe7de4ac8a318b9302864716dde940641a79/wasabi-0.2.2-py3-none-any.whl
  Collecting srsly<1.1.0,>=0.0.6
    Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/b0/63/b68061954228346cbab2c41adb36339678605c47da016f5c71c7ef65f510/srsly-0.1.0.tar.gz
  Collecting numpy>=1.7.0
    Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/90/4e/98818cb208f32833f628d7f7e9dd9ce36cdc34d199ccae0ab37ed6a13b85/numpy-1.17.3-cp38-cp38-win_amd64.whl
  Collecting plac<1.0.0,>=0.9.6
    Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/9e/9b/62c60d2f5bc135d2aa1d8c8a86aaf84edb719a59c7f11a4316259e61a298/plac-0.9.6-py2.py3-none-any.whl
  Collecting tqdm<5.0.0,>=4.10.0
    Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/e1/c1/bc1dba38b48f4ae3c4428aea669c5e27bd5a7642a74c8348451e0bd8ff86/tqdm-4.36.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl
  Installing collected packages: setuptools, wheel, Cython, cymem, preshed, murmurhash, numpy, blis, wasabi, srsly, plac, tqdm, thinc
      Running setup.py install for Cython: started
      Running setup.py install for Cython: finished with status 'done'
      Running setup.py install for cymem: started
      Running setup.py install for cymem: finished with status 'done'
      Running setup.py install for preshed: started
      Running setup.py install for preshed: finished with status 'done'
      Running setup.py install for murmurhash: started
      Running setup.py install for murmurhash: finished with status 'done'
      Running setup.py install for blis: started
      Running setup.py install for blis: finished with status 'error'
      ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
       command: 'c:\program files\python38\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\dougl\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-cn7ebeal\\blis\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\dougl\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-cn7ebeal\\blis\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\dougl\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-j9if9ltu\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --prefix 'C:\Users\dougl\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-1d3wxwlm\overlay' --compile
           cwd: C:\Users\dougl\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-cn7ebeal\blis\
      Complete output (25 lines):
      BLIS_COMPILER? None
      running install
      running build
      running build_py
      creating build
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.8
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\blis
      copying blis\about.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\blis
      copying blis\benchmark.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\blis
      copying blis\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\blis
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\blis\tests
      copying blis\tests\common.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\blis\tests
      copying blis\tests\test_dotv.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\blis\tests
      copying blis\tests\test_gemm.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\blis\tests
      copying blis\tests\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\blis\tests
      copying blis\cy.pyx -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\blis
      copying blis\py.pyx -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\blis
      copying blis\cy.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\blis
      copying blis\__init__.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\blis
      running build_ext
      error: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified
      msvc
      py_compiler msvc
      {'LS_COLORS': 'rs=0:di=01;34:ln=01;36:mh=00:pi=40;33:so=01;35:do=01;35:bd=40;33;01:cd=40;33;01:or=40;31;01:mi=00:su=37;41:sg=30;43:ca=30;41:tw=30;42:ow=34;42:st=37;44:ex=01;32:*.tar=01;31:*.tgz=01;31:*.arc=01;31:*.arj=01;31:*.taz=01;31:*.lha=01;31:*.lz4=01;31:*.lzh=01;31:*.lzma=01;31:*.tlz=01;31:*.txz=01;31:*.tzo=01;31:*.t7z=01;31:*.zip=01;31:*.z=01;31:*.Z=01;31:*.dz=01;31:*.gz=01;31:*.lrz=01;31:*.lz=01;31:*.lzo=01;31:*.xz=01;31:*.zst=01;31:*.tzst=01;31:*.bz2=01;31:*.bz=01;31:*.tbz=01;31:*.tbz2=01;31:*.tz=01;31:*.deb=01;31:*.rpm=01;31:*.jar=01;31:*.war=01;31:*.ear=01;31:*.sar=01;31:*.rar=01;31:*.alz=01;31:*.ace=01;31:*.zoo=01;31:*.cpio=01;31:*.7z=01;31:*.rz=01;31:*.cab=01;31:*.wim=01;31:*.swm=01;31:*.dwm=01;31:*.esd=01;31:*.jpg=01;35:*.jpeg=01;35:*.mjpg=01;35:*.mjpeg=01;35:*.gif=01;35:*.bmp=01;35:*.pbm=01;35:*.pgm=01;35:*.ppm=01;35:*.tga=01;35:*.xbm=01;35:*.xpm=01;35:*.tif=01;35:*.tiff=01;35:*.png=01;35:*.svg=01;35:*.svgz=01;35:*.mng=01;35:*.pcx=01;35:*.mov=01;35:*.mpg=01;35:*.mpeg=01;35:*.m2v=01;35:*.mkv=01;35:*.webm=01;35:*.ogm=01;35:*.mp4=01;35:*.m4v=01;35:*.mp4v=01;35:*.vob=01;35:*.qt=01;35:*.nuv=01;35:*.wmv=01;35:*.asf=01;35:*.rm=01;35:*.rmvb=01;35:*.flc=01;35:*.avi=01;35:*.fli=01;35:*.flv=01;35:*.gl=01;35:*.dl=01;35:*.xcf=01;35:*.xwd=01;35:*.yuv=01;35:*.cgm=01;35:*.emf=01;35:*.ogv=01;35:*.ogx=01;35:*.aac=00;36:*.au=00;36:*.flac=00;36:*.m4a=00;36:*.mid=00;36:*.midi=00;36:*.mka=00;36:*.mp3=00;36:*.mpc=00;36:*.ogg=00;36:*.ra=00;36:*.wav=00;36:*.oga=00;36:*.opus=00;36:*.spx=00;36:*.xspf=00;36:', 'HOSTTYPE': 'x86_64', 'LESSCLOSE': '/usr/bin/lesspipe %s %s', 'LANG': 'C.UTF-8', 'OLDPWD': '/home/matt/repos/flame-blis', 'VIRTUAL_ENV': '/home/matt/repos/cython-blis/env3.6', 'USER': 'matt', 'PWD': '/home/matt/repos/cython-blis', 'HOME': '/home/matt', 'NAME': 'LAPTOP-OMKOB3VM', 'XDG_DATA_DIRS': '/usr/local/share:/usr/share:/var/lib/snapd/desktop', 'SHELL': '/bin/bash', 'TERM': 'xterm-256color', 'SHLVL': '1', 'LOGNAME': 'matt', 'PATH': '/home/matt/repos/cython-blis/env3.6/bin:/tmp/google-cloud-sdk/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/mnt/c/Users/matt/Documents/cmder/vendor/conemu-maximus5/ConEmu/Scripts:/mnt/c/Users/matt/Documents/cmder/vendor/conemu-maximus5:/mnt/c/Users/matt/Documents/cmder/vendor/conemu-maximus5/ConEmu:/mnt/c/Python37/Scripts:/mnt/c/Python37:/mnt/c/Program Files (x86)/Intel/Intel(R) Management Engine Components/iCLS:/mnt/c/Program Files/Intel/Intel(R) Management Engine Components/iCLS:/mnt/c/Windows/System32:/mnt/c/Windows:/mnt/c/Windows/System32/wbem:/mnt/c/Windows/System32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0:/mnt/c/Program Files (x86)/Intel/Intel(R) Management Engine Components/DAL:/mnt/c/Program Files/Intel/Intel(R) Management Engine Components/DAL:/mnt/c/Program Files (x86)/Intel/Intel(R) Management Engine Components/IPT:/mnt/c/Program Files/Intel/Intel(R) Management Engine Components/IPT:/mnt/c/Program Files/Intel/WiFi/bin:/mnt/c/Program Files/Common Files/Intel/WirelessCommon:/mnt/c/Program Files (x86)/NVIDIA Corporation/PhysX/Common:/mnt/c/ProgramData/chocolatey/bin:/mnt/c/Program Files/Git/cmd:/mnt/c/Program Files/LLVM/bin:/mnt/c/Windows/System32:/mnt/c/Windows:/mnt/c/Windows/System32/wbem:/mnt/c/Windows/System32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0:/mnt/c/Windows/System32/OpenSSH:/mnt/c/Program Files/nodejs:/mnt/c/Users/matt/AppData/Local/Microsoft/WindowsApps:/mnt/c/Users/matt/AppData/Local/Programs/Microsoft VS Code/bin:/mnt/c/Users/matt/AppData/Roaming/npm:/snap/bin:/mnt/c/Program Files/Oracle/VirtualBox', 'PS1': '(env3.6) \\[\\e]0;\\u@\\h: \\w\\a\\]${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\\[\\033[01;32m\\]\\u@\\h\\[\\033[00m\\]:\\[\\033[01;34m\\]\\w\\[\\033[00m\\]\\$ ', 'VAGRANT_HOME': '/home/matt/.vagrant.d/', 'LESSOPEN': '| /usr/bin/lesspipe %s', '_': '/home/matt/repos/cython-blis/env3.6/bin/python'}
      clang -c C:\Users\dougl\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-cn7ebeal\blis\blis\_src\config\bulldozer\bli_cntx_init_bulldozer.c -o C:\Users\dougl\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp1sywkk06\bli_cntx_init_bulldozer.o -O2 -funroll-all-loops -std=c99 -D_POSIX_C_SOURCE=200112L -DBLIS_VERSION_STRING="0.5.0-6" -DBLIS_IS_BUILDING_LIBRARY -Iinclude\windows-x86_64 -I.\frame\3\ -I.\frame\ind\ukernels\ -I.\frame\1m\ -I.\frame\1f\ -I.\frame\1\ -I.\frame\include -IC:\Users\dougl\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-cn7ebeal\blis\blis\_src\include\windows-x86_64
      ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'c:\program files\python38\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\dougl\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-cn7ebeal\\blis\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\dougl\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-cn7ebeal\\blis\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\dougl\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-j9if9ltu\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --prefix 'C:\Users\dougl\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-1d3wxwlm\overlay' --compile Check the logs for full command output.
  ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'c:\program files\python38\python.exe' 'c:\program files\python38\lib\site-packages\pip' install --ignore-installed --no-user --prefix 'C:\Users\dougl\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-1d3wxwlm\overlay' --no-warn-script-location --no-binary :none: --only-binary :none: -i https://pypi.org/simple -- setuptools 'wheel>0.32.0,<0.33.0' Cython 'cymem>=2.0.2,<2.1.0' 'preshed>=2.0.1,<2.1.0' 'murmurhash>=0.28.0,<1.1.0' 'thinc>=7.0.8,<7.1.0' Check the logs for full command output
```

Thats the error,if this dont resolve or explain the error, i post the log

Comment: Can you share the actual error message that you get while installing the package?

Comment: @MahendraSingh i post the error code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have a feeling as a noob that spacy does not support Python 3.8 yet. I tried installing it myself on computer with 3.8 and I couldn't, but at work where I use python 3.7 it installed without any issues. Both computers use 64-bit Python.

Comment: I tried here and is that, using python 3.7 and pip he perfectly install the spacy.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try installing spacy with pip before installing chatterbot?

Comment: '''ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'c:\program files\python38\python.exe' 'c:\program files\python38\lib\site-packages\pip' install --ignore-installed --no-user --prefix 'C:\Users\dougl\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-60jdbwtp\normal' --no-warn-script-location --no-binary :none: --only-binary :none: -i https://pypi.org/simple -- 'cython>=0.25' 'cymem<2.1.0,>=2.0.2' 'preshed<3.1.0,>=3.0.2' 'murmurhash<1.1.0,>=0.28.0' 'thinc<7.2.0,>=7.1.1' wheel Check the logs for full command output.'''